# MSVC: "use of class template requires template argument list" inside STL containers

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, stl

I have an issue with nested template classes on MSVC 12 and GCC 4.8. I've reduced it to the following snippet:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Base
{
  template <typename A2, typename B2> struct InBase { };
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Derived : public Base<A, B>
{
  typedef Base<A, B> MyBase;

  // this works on GCC 4.8
  typedef typename MyBase::template InBase<A, B> MyInBase;
  // this works on MSVC 12
  typedef MyBase::InBase<A, B> MyInBase;

  typedef std::vector<MyInBase*> MyInBaseVector;
  typedef std::list<MyInBase*> MyInBaseList;

  MyInBaseList list;
};
```

When I use the MSVC variant of `MyInBase` on GCC, it just tells me to add `typename` and `template`, which I find understandable. When I use the GCC variant on MSVC (which I believe is the correct one), it reports this:

```
deptypes.cpp(20) : error C2955: 'Base<A,B>::InBase' : use of class template requires template argument list
    deptypes.cpp(7) : see declaration of 'Base<A,B>::InBase'
    deptypes.cpp(24) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Derived<A,B>' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\vector(648) : error C2955: 'Base<A,B>::InBase' : use of class template requires template argument list
    deptypes.cpp(7) : see declaration of 'Base<A,B>::InBase'
    deptypes.cpp(7) : see declaration of 'Base<A,B>::InBase'
deptypes.cpp(21) : error C2955: 'Base<A,B>::InBase' : use of class template requires template argument list
    deptypes.cpp(7) : see declaration of 'Base<A,B>::InBase'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\list(859) : error C2955: 'Base<A,B>::InBase' : use of class template requires template argument list
    deptypes.cpp(7) : see declaration of 'Base<A,B>::InBase'
    deptypes.cpp(7) : see declaration of 'Base<A,B>::InBase'
```

Is the MSVC error correct? If yes, how can I fix it?

Comment: I would have thought `typedef typename MyBase::InBase<A, B> MyInBase`

Comment: @NeilKirk: tried it, works for MSVC, but GCC still asks for the ``template`` keyword. So it's more or less the same as before.

Comment: You need both `typename` and `template`. MSVC is just nonconforming there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVC is rejecting valid code here, as [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 14.2 (temp.names) p4 states:

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a
>   *postfix-expression* or after a *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*, and the 
>   object expression of the *postfix-expression* is type-dependent or the
>   *nested-name-specifier* in the *qualified-id* refers to a dependent type, but the name 
>   is not a member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must 
>   be prefixed by the keyword `template`. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a 
>   non-template.

Given this, I checked your sample against ICC 13 and Clang 3.3 on [Godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org): ICC correctly rejects this MSVC-ism with `nontype "Base<A, B>::InBase [with A=A, B=B]" is not a template` while accepting the conformant (`typename`/`template` qualified) version, whereas Clang, interestingly enough, accepts both the conformant *and* the nonconformant typedefs!  My local copy of MSVC 11 (VS2012) also rejects the version with `template` and `typename` in it, as well as passing a template argument list as the error suggests (which is ill-formed in any case).

It appears that the `template` keyword is what is tripping MSVC up, too, which prevents GCC 4.9's suggestion of using an otherwise-redundant `Derived::MyBase::template InBase<A, B>` to force the expression into a dependent context without using `typename` from working.

The Visual Studio devs are already [aware of a very similar issue to this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/752908). As to working around it, though? You'll just have to use a `#ifdef _MSC_VER` block to cage the MSVC-specific version of the typedef.

For pedants: ICC, for all it gets ripped on in some corners of the world, *does* conform to the C++ standards in practice, as it uses the same EDG frontend as Comeau C++.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis. My current workaround, which works without ifdefs, is to use a struct to wrap the pointer, and then put that struct into the vector.